# AngularJS don't work on view page when references on ViewMasterPage

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use angularJS in an old asp.net mvc appication.

This application uses a ViewMasterPage

If I load the angularjs reference in the viewpage, it works just fine:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ng") %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title></title>    
</head>

<div ng-app="">

    <p>{{ "Hello" + " World" }}</p>
    <p>{{ 2 + 4 }}</p>

</div>

</script>

</html>
```

[OUTPUT ANGULAR OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juHFl.png)

but when I try lo load the reference to angular JS in the view master page, it doesnt work.

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js") +"?"+ version %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js") +"?"+ version %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.min.js") +"?" + version%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js") +"?"+ version %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know for sure, that is loading the script file, because if I load in both viewmasterpage and viewpage I'm getting this error:

WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does the view page have html and head tags if it is rendered by a master page?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just remove it, I'm kinda new in this, so I'm not really sure how to use it. I'm still having the problem, any idea? thank you in advance

Comment: Please, update your question to reflect the changes you've made.

Comment: Can you include your whole master page as it looks when you include the angular.js reference?

Comment: it seems that the whole problem come from the way the application is build, regarding the masterviewpage and the bad reference with the viewpage, thanks to your comment I know where to look, so I'm going to close the question for now. I really appreaciate your help, greetings.